# Joomla admin add new group with custom default group parent

Tags: joomla

in *Joolma* admin

*`administrator/index.php?option=com_users&view=group&layout=edit`*

when adding a new group the default Group `Parent = Public`

any idea how to get another default group selected? (my customer needs it daily and sometimes forget to choose the good Group Parent)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not advisable to alter core files because when you update Joomla it may change this modified files. But currently I dont find any other alternative method to achieve what you need.
If you visit the user group page you will see on the right side the group ID's

[image]

if you open this file administrator\components\com_users\models\forms\group.xml you will find this code

```
<field name="parent_id" type="groupparent"
            description="COM_USERS_GROUP_FIELD_PARENT_DESC"
            label="COM_USERS_GROUP_FIELD_PARENT_LABEL"
            required="true"
        />
```

There is no default mentioned in this but you can add a default parent id here like this

```
<field name="parent_id" type="groupparent"
            description="COM_USERS_GROUP_FIELD_PARENT_DESC"
            label="COM_USERS_GROUP_FIELD_PARENT_LABEL"
            default="5"
            required="true"
        />
```

This will make Publisher as default parent. There is even one more way to do this but it may need several code changes i.e changing the file administrator\components\com_users\models\fields\groupparent.php. Hope this helps.

Comment: By the way I changed article.xml too , to get the default selected category needed

Comment: Before changing anything in article.xml file just check if that can be done through backend admin panel. That is best way to do and this comes next. Anyways happy learning.